# jquery.getJSON giving error

Tags: jquery, json, get

here is the code which is giving error

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var reqUrl='https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/slug:blogging-and-stuff';

   $.getJSON(reqUrl,function(data) {
          alert(data);   
   }).error(function() { alert("error"); });

</script>
```

I have wasted hours,but have not got success.visiting the url in browser is giving valid JSON.

The url I need to work with is 
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/slug:blogging-and-stuff

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX calls. There are some workarounds depending on the level of control you have over the remote domain. Checkout the [following guide](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide).

- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (requires you to have control over the remote domain)
- [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (requires you to have control over the remote domain)
- Server side script bridge on your domain (doesn't require you to have control over the remote domain)

---

UPDATE:

OK, now that you have shown the actual url, it seems that it supports JSONP. Here's how to consume it:

```
var reqUrl = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/slug:blogging-and-stuff?callback=?';

$.getJSON(reqUrl,function(data) {
    alert(data);   
}).error(function() { alert('error'); });
```

​
Notice the `?callback=?` parameter that I have appended to the end of your url.

And here's a live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/6S4TP/

Comment: but see JSONP which does let you return JSON x-domain: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: @BobTodd, yes of course, but the url that the OP showed here doesn't return JSONP. It returns JSON which is not the same thing at all. That's why his AJAX call doesn't work. In the getJSON documentation they are consuming the flickr API which supports JSONP.

Comment: OK, now that you have shown your real url see my updated answer that will work.

Comment: now when problem is solved,one final doubt.
is there no way to consume http://cloudspokes.com/challenges.json from javascript,even when its public api ?

Comment: It will depend on whether this API supports JSONP. Read the documentation of this API.